# Installing Windows Mobile SDK without Visual Studio

Tags: installation, windows-mobile, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

Is it possible to install the Windows Mobile SDK without having Visual Studio?  I am using SharpDevelop to write a Windows Mobile application, but I need to use an assembly in the Windows Mobile 6.0 SDK.  When I try to install the SDK I get a message that says Visual Studio is a prerequisite, and I am un able to install it.

Is there a way to trick it in to thinking Visual Studio is installed; maybe a registry entry that can be added or something, or am I just hosed?  Is there a reason I need to pay for Microsoft's IDE, or is this just a way for Microsoft to make some extra money?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are writing an application that targets the .NET Compact Framework.  If that is true, you should able to get all of the assemblies in the CF from the [.NET Framework SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=fe6f2099-b7b4-4f47-a244-c96d69c35dec&displaylang=en), which includes the CF command-line development tools.

Comment: I only need one assembly Miscrosoft.WindowsMobile.PocketOutlook.dll.  The application I am writing relies on it to intercept incoming text messages, unless there is another way to intercept incoming messages that fit a particular criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to unpack the contents of the SDK installer using a tool like 7-Zip. After you have extracted the DLL's from the SDK, you should be able to manually add them as a project reference.

Comment: How do I unpack the installer?

Comment: `msiexec /a "MSI File.msi" /qb TARGETDIR="Full path to target directory"` to unpack MSI files. 7-Zip to unpack any associated binary or compressed files. Its been a while since I did this myself, but you should only need `msiexec` and there is a second msi file within the first.